# When I write the image it appears black

Tags: matlab, grayscale

I have a program that returns a `grayscale` image. But, when I try to write the image, it appears totally `black`. Why is that? How can I write the image and get the expected result?

Thanks.

Comment: try one of these: imshow(img,[])  or  imshow(uint8(img)). If this works the reason is as stated in the answer below. Your values were too low to display or it was not of the right class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First check on the type of your data. You can cast the type of the data by example *double()* or *uint16()* etc. (Check the help for typecasting).
Here is an example how you rescale your values to the intensity-range of uint16, unsigned integers with ~65k possible different values. The casting of course leads to less precision of the intensity values.

```
new_img(:,:) = uint16((new_img(:,:)./max(max(new_img(:,:),[],1)))*65536);
```

Afterwards you should be able to write the data to your file.

Comment: It seems here that the saved image would be binary?

Comment: To add to Barkel his comment: The file type (extension: e.g. *.jpeg) you want to save in makes a difference. Let's say you're using the function "imwrite" then you want to also think of the filetype you want to save in. Not all filetypes accept all datatypes. For me, a simple trick that most often works is using the "mat2gray" function on your image before you want to save. But remember that it might scale data in a way you find undesirable.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that your grayscaled image is of the right class. Furthermore check the values in the generated image. If they're simply too low all will appear black. If you can provide more specific information it might be possible to give a more elaborate answer.

Answer (score 0):

if you're working on a binary image(before being converted to gray) and you about to convert it to gray-scale, then you suddenly change the range of pixels from [0, 1] to [0, 255]. so the value '1' in binary image is totally white but in gray-scale image is almost black.

try this:

```
img = imread('image_name.jpg');
imshow(img*50)
```

it make you sure that you image is black or just its pixel-values aren't appropriate.