# Writing TIFF Appears Black But imagesc does not MATLAB

Tags: matlab, casting, tiff

I want to write a tiff again after having read it into MATLAB. The tiff files were generated by some other software:

```
[flnm,locn]=uigetfile({'*.tif','Image files'}, 'Select an image');       
fp=fullfile(locn,flnm);        
I = double(imread(fp));    
info = imfinfo(fp);



.   
.
.

J2 = im2int16(J2);       
J2(:,:) = uint16((J2(:,:)./max(max(J2(:,:),[],1)))*65536);       

T = Tiff((fullfile(strcat(locn,v_f), (sprintf('%d.tif',i)))), 'w');        

tagstruct.ImageLength = size(J2, 1);         
tagstruct.ImageWidth = size(J2, 2);        
tagstruct.Compression = Tiff.Compression.None;        
tagstruct.SampleFormat = Tiff.SampleFormat.Int;         
tagstruct.Photometric = Tiff.Photometric.MinIsBlack;         
tagstruct.BitsPerSample = info.BitsPerSample; % 32;         
tagstruct.SamplesPerPixel = info.SamplesPerPixel; % 1;         
tagstruct.PlanarConfiguration = Tiff.PlanarConfiguration.Chunky;         
T.setTag(tagstruct);         
T.write(J2);         
T.close();
```

This line which is supposed to rescale the intensity range:

```
J2(:,:) = uint16((J2(:,:)./max(max(J2(:,:),[],1)))*65536);
```

was borrowed from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19949536/3319527. But my images still come out as black. This should not be the case because with imagesc though the signals are quite noisy but the data output to the screen makes sense but the tiffs I write to file are quite useless.

Image Parameters:

```
Filename: [1x172 char]
                  FileModDate: '24-Jan-2014 14:39:09'
                     FileSize: 32003
                       Format: 'tif'
                FormatVersion: []
                        Width: 125
                       Height: 125
                     BitDepth: 16
                    ColorType: 'grayscale'
              FormatSignature: [73 73 42 0]
                    ByteOrder: 'little-endian'
               NewSubFileType: 0
                BitsPerSample: 16
                  Compression: 'Uncompressed'
    PhotometricInterpretation: 'BlackIsZero'
                 StripOffsets: [8 2008 4008 6008 8008 10008 12008 14008 16008 18008 20008 22008 24008 26008 28008 30008]
              SamplesPerPixel: 1
                 RowsPerStrip: 8
              StripByteCounts: [2000 2000 2000 2000 2000 2000 2000 2000 2000 2000 2000 2000 2000 2000 2000 1250]
                  XResolution: 72
                  YResolution: 72
               ResolutionUnit: 'Inch'
                     Colormap: []
          PlanarConfiguration: 'Chunky'
                    TileWidth: []
                   TileLength: []
                  TileOffsets: []
               TileByteCounts: []
                  Orientation: 1
                    FillOrder: 1
             GrayResponseUnit: 0.0100
               MaxSampleValue: 65535
               MinSampleValue: 0
                 Thresholding: 1
                       Offset: 31768
             ImageDescription: '
```

From tiff info:

```
TIFF File: '000001.tif'
                       Mode: 'r'
    Current Image Directory: 1
           Number Of Strips: 16
                SubFileType: Tiff.SubFileType.Default
                Photometric: Tiff.Photometric.MinIsBlack
                ImageLength: 125
                 ImageWidth: 125
               RowsPerStrip: 8
              BitsPerSample: 16
                Compression: Tiff.Compression.None
               SampleFormat: Tiff.SampleFormat.UInt
            SamplesPerPixel: 1
        PlanarConfiguration: Tiff.PlanarConfiguration.Chunky
           ImageDescription: 

This is frame #0000           
                Orientation: Tiff.Orientation.TopLeft
```

Thanks!

Comment: I see the comment `%32` on the `BitsPerSample` line, yet you're using `uint16`. What are the specs on the input image?

Comment: Why are you using `im2int16` rather than `im2uint16`? And by the way, `(:,:)` is redundant for a grayscale image.